# How to prevent remove operation in Json Patch Document .NET Core Web API

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, patch, webapi

I'm using .NET core and EF in my Web API project.

I want to have a Patch end point to update an entity. I found this article which says

> Remove Similar to the “Add” operation outlined above, the Remove
> Operation typically means you are either removing a property from an
> object or removing an item from an array. But because you can’t
> actually “remove” a property from an object in C#, what actually
> happens is that it will set the value to default(T). In some cases if
> the object is nullable (Or a reference type), it will be set to NULL.
> But be careful because when used on value types, for example an int,
> then the value actually gets reset to “0”.

I don't want the client to send a remove operation which will reset some of his fields or adding a new filed using `Add` operation

So here I want to create the PATCH end point to update the person `FirstName` or `Age` using `replace` operation only.

I have a `Person` entity and `UpdatePersonDTO` like below

```
public partial class Person
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public int Age { get; set; }
}

public partial class PersonDTO
{
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public int Age { get; set; }
}
```

This the current code I have

```
public async Task<Object> UpdatePerson(int id , JsonPatchDocument<PersonRequestDTO> patchDocument) {

var result = _dbContext.persons
   .Where(P => P.id == id).FirstOrDefault();


var personToPatch = _mapper.Map<PersonRequestDTO>(result);
patchDocument.ApplyTo(personToPatch);
_mapper.Map(personToPatch, result);

// rest of code and returning updated entitiy dto... 
}
```

Now what is the way to achieve that? and why I couldn't find questions similar to this?
I think the `remove` operation is very critical , so now I'm feeling that I'm actually missing something here.

Comment: What article? Your code updates a `Person` object with specific properties stored to a table with specific columns. It can't add or remove fields and columns. At best, it will set the properties to `null` or `0` which is no different than updating the object and explicitly setting them to `null` or 0

Comment: In fact, the very extract you posted says that attributes *can't* be removed. Assuming you read [this article](https://dotnetcoretutorials.com/2017/11/29/json-patch-asp-net-core/) it explains that attributes can't be added or removed.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Yes you are correct. The only difference is that the data that will be sent from our front-end will never be 0 or null they always come with valid data. We allow user to choose data from drop-down list that mapped to our database. The Model is not a Person but I choose Person for simplicity. And here's the article https://dotnetcoretutorials.com/2017/11/29/json-patch-asp-net-core/

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I'm concerned about setting the attributes value to 0 or null when using remove

Comment: How is this any different than using a PUT to set them to `0` ? Or a `replace` ? If you don't want those fields to be nullable, specify it in the entity, table column and validations. A `NOT NULL` column can't be set to `NULL`. A `[Required]` property can't be NULL. BTW the mapper doesn't offer anything here. You don't need that `PersonDTO`. The [documentation example](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/web-api/jsonpatch?view=aspnetcore-5.0#action-method-code) is a lot simpler *and* uses validation. With `patchDoc.ApplyTo(customer, ModelState);` you can check `ModelState.IsValid`

Comment: `Id` can't be changed either if it's database-generated. Besides, you can always check if `result.Id` is equal to `id` before saving

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Thank you for the information. However let's say the field (age) is nullable in the database for some reason. but we are not allowing user to enter a null or 0 value. So our front-end team will make sure that the age is not 0 or null. But what if the API got exposed to the external world and someone used remove and set the age to null or 0! (Age is just an example) Hope my point is clear by now

Comment: I've already answered that. You can use validation rules to ensure the values are valid *before* storing the data. You can use validation attributes, Fluent validation or custom code

Comment: I'm using Fluent Validation in the project and it's working fine with GET end points but with PATCH and JsonPatchDocument it didn't work and that's why I couldn't proceeds

Comment: @Jack Then why not ask a question about *that* instead?

Comment: @Jack do you mean that after `patchDoc.ApplyTo(person, ModelState);` you get the wrong `ModelState.IsValid`? This is a different question.

Answer (score 2):

As the article says, `Add` and `Remove` can't add or remove attributes in C#, only array items. A `remove` is equivalent to setting the attribute to `null`, or if it's a value type, to its default.

Validation rules and attributes can detect this. The [JSON Patch example in the ASP.NET Core docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/web-api/jsonpatch?view=aspnetcore-5.0#action-method-code) shows exactly this scenario. With a slight modification :

```
[HttpPatch]
public IActionResult JsonPatchWithModelState(
    int id,
    [FromBody] JsonPatchDocument<Person> patchDoc)
{
    if (patchDoc != null)
    {
        var person = _dbContext.persons
                         .Find(id)
                         .FirstOrDefault();

        patchDoc.ApplyTo(person, ModelState);

        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            return BadRequest(ModelState);
        }

        _dbContext.SaveChanges();
        return new ObjectResult(person);

    }
    else
    {
        return BadRequest(ModelState);
    }
}
```

Adding validation attributes to the `Person` class will ensure it can't accept invalid data :

```
public partial class Person
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string FirstName { get; set; }

    [Range(1,199)]
    public int Age { get; set; }
}
```

If we fear the `PATCH` may modify the ID, and the field is *not* database-generated, we can check that the `person.id` is unchanged :

```
if (!ModelState.IsValid || person.id!=id)
{
    if (person.id!=id)
    {
        ModelState.AddError("id","Not Editable");
    }
    return BadRequest(ModelState);
}
```

Comment: Checking  if (person.id!=id) will always return true since you are populating the person object using the passed id.